# Como conecto una FK a una PK compuesta

Tags: sql, sql-server, transact-sql

Hola tengo la siguiente tabla CELDA

```
CREATE TABLE Celda
 (ID_CELDA INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  ID_PARQUEADERO INT,
  TAMAÑO_CELDA INT,
  PLACA_VEHICULO VARCHAR(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (ID_CELDA, ID_PARQUEADERO))

y la Siguiente tabla Denuncia

CREATE TABLE Denuncia
 (ID_DENUNCIA BIGINT IDENTITY(1000,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  DOCUMENTO_PROPIETARIO BIGINT NOT NULL,
  ID_PARQUEADERO INT,
  ID_CELDA INT)
```

Quiero unir a ID_PARQUEADERO, ID_CELDA de la tabla Denuncia con ID_PARQUEADERO, ID_CELDA de la tabla Celda.

Puse en la tabla Celda a ID_PARQUEADERO y ID_CELDA como PK para poder saber a que parqueadero pertenece cada Celda.

Son varios Parqueaderos que pueden tener el mismo nombre de Celdas, pero en un mismo parqueadero no pueden haber 2 Celdas repetidas.

Al poner el CONSTRAINT me da error

```
ALTER TABLE Denuncia ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Denuncia_ID_PARQUEADERO FOREIGN KEY (ID_PARQUEADERO) REFERENCES CELDA(ID_PARQUEADERO)

ALTER TABLE Denuncia ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Denuncia_ID_CELDA FOREIGN KEY (ID_CELDA) REFERENCES CELDA(ID_CELDA)
```

> ERROR: Mens. 1776, Nivel 16, Estado 0, Línea 109
> No hay claves principales ni candidatas en la tabla a la que se hace referencia ('CELDA') que concuerden con la lista de columnas que hace la referencia en la clave externa 'FK_Denuncia_ID_PARQUEADERO'.
> Mens. 1750, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 109
> No se pudo crear la restricción o el índice. Vea los errores anteriores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Ya encontré la solución, para mi caso era poner todo en una sola instrucción, ya que voy a relacionar 2 FK con una PK compuesta por 2 campos.

El código seria así:

```
ALTER TABLE Denuncia 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Denuncia_ID_PARQUEADERO_ID_CELDA 
FOREIGN KEY (ID_CELDA,ID_PARQUEADERO) 
REFERENCES CELDA(ID_CELDA,ID_PARQUEADERO)
```

Comment: Para que quede claro, relacionas 1 FK compuesta con 1 PK compuesta. No son 2 FK.